# creating a simple quiz app in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need some help to get started with a simple quiz app on windows phone 7.
Users will have to guess what is the name of a given place in my city shown in a picture.
There will be a picture on the screen and right beneath it there will be 4 answers, if a user clicks on the correct one he will be notifed of the correct answer and then he can go to another question, same with incorrect asnwer scenario. I need to keep track of correct answers. So I need help or direction of how to set up such questions/answers game. I need the questions to be all random generated (4 random asnwers per question) and let say I will have 10 questions per game.

I'm planning to have a list that will hold my city places

```
  cityList = new List<string>();

        cityList.Add("answer1");
        cityList.Add("answer2");
        cityList.Add("asnwer3");
        cityList.Add("answer4");
```

and i'm stuck, anyone that has done similar thing before please help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. I typed this in the answer box, it probably wont complile as is, but will definitely get you started.

```
class Question

{
    string ImageURI { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

    bool MakeGuess(Answer a) { UserGuess = a; if (a.Equals(CorrectAnswer)) {  return true; } return false; }

    bool AnsweredSuccessfully { get { return UserGuess != null && UserGuess.Equals(CorrectAnswer); } }
    Answer UserGuess { get; set; }

}

class Answer 
{
   string text { get; set; }
}
class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
         Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Questions.Add(GenerateQuestion()); }
    }
    public Question GenerateQuestion()
    {
       Question q = new Question();
       q.ImageURI = your link to image//;
       q.Text = your image text//;
       q.Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
       q.CorrectAnswer = the correct answer//;
       q.Answers.Add(CorrectAnswer);

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { q.Answers.Add(GenerateAnswer(q.CorrectAnswer)); }

       return q;
    }
   public Answer GenerateAnswer(Answer ignore) 
{
     List<Answer> answers = DataStore.Answers;//go to your main list of answers.

     Random rand = new Random();

     Answer a = answers[Random.Next(0,answers.Size())];
     while (a == null || a.Equals(ignore) {  a = answers[Random.Next(0,answers.Size())];}
     return a;
}
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make my own class Puzzle which would look like this one:

```
public class Puzzle 
{
     List<string> answers = new List<string>(4);

     public Puzzle(string question, List<string> answers, int correctAnswer)
     {
           Question = question;
           Answers = answers;
           CorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
     }
     public string Question {get; private set;}
     public int CorrectAnswer {get; private set;} //or you can make CorrectAnswer a string
     public List<string> Answers { get { return answers;} }

}
```

This class would need logic for dataBiding if you use one, maybe some interface.

Your list would look like this:

```
cityPlaces = new List<string>(); //guess that's a better name
var answersOne = new List<string>() { "bla1", "bla2", "bla3", "bla4"};
cityPlaces .Add("What is the blabla blabla?",answersOne,2);
```

I have doubts about "I need the questions to be all random generated". I think that's not the best idea for this kind of game. Better is to make the question and answers shown in random order. Use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to show them in a random order ([here is a C# example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html), the first one, second is wrong, GUID is unique not random and sort algorithm may do anything with this kind of comparator f.e. crash).

That should help you.